# Add product to cart buttom

Tags: forms, shopify, liquid

I wonder if there is a way on shopify liquid, to make a add to cart button.
I made a button but it jumps to the cart page, while I only want to add the product and stay at the same page.

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">
            <input name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" type="hidden" />
            <input name="add" value="ORDER NOW" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Shopify AJAX API to add items in your cart without refreshing the page.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax/reference/cart

Add to cart through form:

```
jQuery.post(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', $('form[action$="/cart/add"]').serialize());
```

Retrieve cart items:

```
var cartContents = fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart.js')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { return data });
```